# How do I remove the glow on plank dock when an app is focused on?

Tags: dock, focus, plank

I want to remove this glow on plank anybody know how?

[image: glow]

I opened the dock.theme file and the only way i could make it disappear was to make `TopPadding=-12` which will just basically make my whole dock transparent.